# The form is not submitted once submitted with invalid input?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a javascript function like this:

```
   function validateInput() {
        var search_text = document.getElementById('search_text').value;
        var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
        var submitButton = document.getElementById('sb_search');
        document.getElementById('sb_search').disabled=false;
        var filter = /^[\x20-\x7E]*$/;

        if (filter.test(search_text) && search_text.length>0){
                   return true;
        }

        else{
             submitButton.setAttribute('disabled');

             } 

         }
```

Once I press the submit button without value and without satisfying the regex the button is not submitted after that.

Comment: your question is v unclear. when the regex is not satisfied, and input is blank, the submit button **should** get disabled. that is your code!

Comment: Yes, now when after satisfying the regex and after the input is not blank the form is even not submitted.

Comment: put an alert inside the `if` and check whether it is going in or not.

Comment: do as per my answer below = `document.getElementById('sb_search').removeAttribute('disabled')`

Answer (score 0):

you are disabling the submit button when the input is zero or not as per the regex !

also you are not returning true which is holding it from submition !

Comment: That's what I need. It stop from the form submission the fist time. But after that even if I input the value the form is not submitted.

Comment: you should go with @Rhea 's answer

Answer (score 0):

- put a `return false` in the else condition.
- instead of `document.getElementById('sb_search').disabled=false;` try 
  `document.getElementById('sb_search').removeAttribute('disabled')`

Answer (score 0):

Put return false in else statement

```
    function validateInput() {
    var search_text = document.getElementById('search_text').value;
    var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('sb_search');
    document.getElementById('sb_search').disabled=false;
    var filter = /^[\x20-\x7E]*$/;

    if (filter.test(search_text) && search_text.length>0){
               return true;
    }

    else{
         submitButton.setAttribute('disabled');
         return false;
         } 

     }
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because `search_text.length == 0` and thus you fall into the `else` and disable the submit button

Comment: downvoting without commenting is lame!